# Zend Framework custom URL

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting, routes

I make a project with Zend, i'm new. And this is my idea:

http://mydomain.com/username

Will show content same as:
--> http://mydomain.com/profile/index/u/username

and http://mydomain.com/username/gallery

Will show content same as:
--> http://mydomain.com/profile/gallery/u/username

( profile controller )

Can Zend does something like this?

Please help. Thanks so much.

And right now, I'm learning Zend 1.1.1 as primaty download on their website, but I 'm seeing Zend 2.x is Beta. Should I still learn Zend 1.x ? or waiting Zend 2.x come out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .htaccess rewrites for this.

or add another route that executes the same controller action:

```
$router->addRoute(
    'profile_2',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':username', array(
        'controller' => 'profile',
        'action' => 'showUser'
    ))
);
```

Comment: do you know how to check if Controller is not exist, then add this Route? Because if add this Route, all controllers will be thinking as :username

Answer (score 0):

U can use this piece of magic route ;)

```
$router = Zend_Front_Controller::getInstance()->getRouter();    
$router->addRoute(
    'user',
     new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':u/:action', array(
        'controller' => 'profile',
        'action' => 'index',
        'u' => null
    ))
);
```

Comment: place it **after** your **default** route